# Does Android package name matters for search in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

We have an app named "The Right Words". But it's package name is "ru.lextre.poetizr". Does it harm us when users search for our app in Play Store? I understand that the user-readable name is kinda generic, but at least it should appear quite high when searching for quoted string, shouldn't it? Right now, it appears somewhere in the middle of results, and if the search string is unquoted, it does not appear at all.

For example, The Real World app, which is also kinda generic, appears high in search for their name, despite having almost zero downloads.

Comment: They are not as important as your app name and app description. An ordinary non techy users will not use Package in searching.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play makes it possible to search by package name. But I don't think it matters for search rankings.

If you have just released your app Google Play needs some time for indexing. But searching by package name works just after a new release.

Things that really matters are keywords in title and description, number of given user ratings and its score, amount of downloads and uninstalls.

Comment: Aha, thank you. We already received several confirmations that package name does not matter, so I guess this is it.